# Raspberry Pi over-voltaged I2C pins - is it possible to fix them?

Tags: raspberry-pi, repair

I made a silly mistake and over-voltaged one of my I2C devices connected to my Raspberry Pi 4, by putting 24 V on a 5 V device..yikes. Unfortunately, but not surprisingly, this seems to have killed my GPIO pins for my I2C. I seemed to have gotten away with any further damage to the Pi.

Pi's are pretty costly these days. Does anyone know if this is a semi-easy fix?

I've got semi-decent soldering facilities so I'm hoping and praying this fix is as simple as me buying a replacement for a burnt-out chip and soldering it on. Does anyone have any advice/experience/comments on this?

I would be highly appreciative of any and all help as I've never fixed a Pi before.

Edit: If anyone knows of a GPIO breakout that could prevent damage in the future from happening (ie a fuse or diode between the 'true' gpio and the breakout pins) I would be grateful to hear about it- it seems very risky given how easy it's been to bridge 5V on one of the GPIO pins.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You did burn out part of a chip, but unfortunately, that chip is the main SoC of the Pi - the big, expensive one that contains the CPU (and RAM depending on the model). The GPIO lines connect directly to it.

There's no way to fix this. The GPIOs are toast; the transistors within the SoC that drive and sense them are fried.

Comment: The SoC does not contain the RAM

Comment: Thanks for this Jonathan. Is there any work around at all, maybe not fixing the I2C Pins but by remapping pins or perhaps there's some breakout board that can fulfill the same role? It feels a shame to scrap a perfectly good, working pi (apart from 2 pins)

Comment: You can use software I2C on alternate GPIOs.

Comment: there also a second I2C that's "reserved" but can still be used if you don't need compatibility with other hardware.

Comment: Thanks @Jasen , how do you mean other hardware? Will I still be able to connect my i2c breakout boards to this other i2c?

Comment: other hardware: HATs mostly - they use this I2C for device ID and configuration.